# python substring not being printed

Tags: python, find, substring

I can't figure whats wrong with this part of code

```
if value.find("\\") > -1:
    newstr = int(value.find("\\"))
    print newstr
    print value
    print value[newstr:7]
```

the `newstr` is being printed correctly as well as the `value` but the `value[newstr:7]` show blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: nothing, fixed it =)  should be newstr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value[newstr:7]` will give you from position `newstr` up to position `7`.

Perhaps you meant `value[newstr:newstr + 7]`?

Comment: I want to get a substring beginning from where I found a "\" plus 7 positions.